# Need to disable buttons on the window if several conditions are not met

Tags: wpf, data-binding, binding

My WPF application has a number of buttons on its main window.  I'm working on an edge case right now where the buttons should be disabled if the database is down or if the application can't establish a connection to its back-end (the back-end is a Windows service we've written).

There are two classes in my View Model library called `DbMonitor` and `ComMonitor` ("Com" for "Communications").  They descend from an the same abstract class, implement the `IPropertyChanged` interface, and have a property called `Status` (inherited from the abstract base class) which is an enumeration called `DeviceStatuses` with values `Green`, `Yellow`, and `Red`.  I want the Buttons to be enabled only if the Status properties of both objects are `Green`?

How do get this binding to work in the Xaml, or do I have to do this in my code-behind.

Thanks

Tony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After asking the question, I did some additional research and found a solution that works for me.

I created a class that implements the IMultiConverter interface that converts my `DeviceStatuses` enumeration to bool.  Then, in my Xaml, I did this:

```
<Button ....>
    <Button.IsEnabled>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource DeviceStatusToBool}">
            <Binding Path="..." />
            <Binding Path="..." />
        </MuntiBinding>
    </Button.IsEnabled>
</Button>
```

This works very well.

I can't convert the buttons to use ICommand at this point.  Not enough time before our release date.

Tony

Comment: you really have to look into the Delegate/RelayCommand stuff if you wanna use real Viewmodel.. makes your code much more easier

Comment: You could declare a property in VM bool ButtonIsEnabled and directly bind it with the Button Property IsEnabled="{Binding ButtonIsEnabled}" and in VM you could set ButtonIsEnabled to true or false based on your condition. But using ICommand is the way to go.

Answer (score 4):

Are you using Commands with these buttons? If not, how hard would it be for you to switch to commands? The `CanExecute` part of `ICommand` seems like the way to go here.

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways to go about this:
**1.  Bind IsEnabled propetry** of your button to your Status property with a Converter to map from DeviceStatus to bool (enabled or not).  I wouldn't recomend this.
**2. RoutedCommands**:

```
public static RoutedCommand MyButtonCommand = new RoutedCommand();
private void CommandBinding_MyButtonEnabled(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e) {
    e.CanExecute = Db.Monitor.Status==DeviceStatuses.Green;
}
```

and bind to it in XAML:

```
<Window.CommandBindings>
<CommandBinding
    Command="{x:Static p:Window1.MyButtonCommand}"
    Executed="buttonMyButton_Executed"
    CanExecute="CommandBinding_MyButtonEnabled" />
</Window.CommandBindings>  
<Button Content="My Button" Command="{x:Static p:Window1.MyButtonCommand}"/>
```

**3. Implement ICommand**:

```
public class MyCmd : ICommand {
    public virtual bool CanExecute(object parameter) {
        return Db.Monitor.Status==DeviceStatuses.Green;
    }
}
```

Here the Command is a property of the appropriate view model:

```
class MyViewModel {
    public MyCmd myCcmd { get; set; }
}
```

and you bind to it in XAML:

```
<Button Content="My Button" Command="{Binding myCmd}"/>
```

The third approach is normally the most flexible.  You would need to inject the view model that has your status properties into the the Command constructor so you can implement your CanExecute logic.